# Trying to fetch all data with a while loop but the first data is already fetched, don't know how to change my code. (Php)

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, fetch, categories

So here's an example code I use to show all the categories that are linked to a certain postID. 
For example post 1 has the categories: Apple, Green and Yellow linked to it.

But I can't seem to fetch the data correctly since it has already been fetched once at the top i can't do a proper while loop at the `Categories:` part of my code where I try to do a while loop. The while loop works and fetches all the categories except the First one and also when I place the while loop the

> $row['postTitle']

and

> $row['postCont']

won't appear anymore because it's being skipped. How would I fix something like this? Thanks.

---

```
<?php require('includes/config.php'); 

$stmt = $db->prepare("  SELECT * 
                        FROM blog_posts 
                        LEFT JOIN  blog_posts_categories ON blog_posts.postID=blog_posts_categories.postID 
                        INNER JOIN blog_categories ON blog_posts_categories.catID=blog_categories.catID 
                        WHERE blog_posts.postID = :postID");

$stmt->execute(array(':postID' => $_GET['id']));
$row = $stmt->fetch();

//if post does not exists redirect user to homepage.
if($row['postID'] == ''){
    header('Location: ./');
    exit;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?php echo $row['postTitle'];?> | Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <h1>Single Post Page</h1>
        <hr />
        <p><a href="./">Home</a> | 

            Categories: 

            <?php while($row = $stmt->fetch())
            {
                //the first category is being skipped? How to fix?
                echo $row['catName'];
            } ?>

        </p>
        <div>
            <?php 
                //these won't appear because of the while loop. It's being skipped.
                echo '<h1>'.$row['postTitle'].'</h1>';
                echo '<p>'.$row['postCont'].'</p>'; 
            ?>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have an extra `$row = $stmt->fetch();` on the top !

Comment: Yes I know, but if I remove that one my whole code won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace:

```
        while($row = $stmt->fetch())
        {
            echo $row['catName'];
        }
```

With:

```
        do {
            echo $row['catName'];
        } while($row = $stmt->fetch());
```

As for the other items - put them **inside** the loop obviously instead of afterwards.

Comment: Your a genius haha thanks it worked!!!! THank you

But now I'm facing another problem my: $row['postTitle'] and $row['postCont'] and whatever won't appear it's content

EDIT: i tried to put them inside the loop but I don't want them to be appearing more than 1 time

Comment: As said, put them inside the loop if you want them to be evaluated inside the loop. Can't make it much clearer than that....

Comment: Niels excuses daarvoor haha had het te snel gelezen!

I've edited my first comment

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this answer works. Would you care to elaborate? :)

Comment: I tried to put my other items outside the the do while loop like this:

`do {
            echo $row['catName'];
        } while($row = $stmt->fetch());

echo '<h1>'.$row['postTitle'].'</h1>';
                echo '<p>'.$row['postCont'].'</p>'; `

but nothing appears for them